# Is there a way to color output of ndk-build?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, makefile

Do you know if there is a way to color the output of calling `ndk-build` in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

`Clang` from the latest `Android NDK` produces color output. Just put this line into your `Application.mk`:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```